# Why does Next.js not have access to remote images at build time?

Tags: image, next.js, server-side-rendering

When using a local image with Next.js, it automatically provides `blurDataURL` which is generated based off the primary image.

However, when using a remote image the `blurDataURL` needs to be provided separately. The [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images#remote-images) say this is because Next doesn't have access to the remote files at build time.

What is stopping Next from accessing the image and generating a blurred version with URL during the build process?